# How to resolve the Slim framework error "404 Page Not Found"?

Tags: php, post, dictionary, get, slim

I'm using **Slim framework** for my project. I've copied the Slim folder to my project directory.

No following is the code I'm having issue with :

**HTML code (multiplemethods.html):**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Multiple Methods Routing Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="multiplemethodsroute.php/products" method="GET">

            product id <input type="text" name="id" />
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" />
    </form> 
  </body>   
</html>
```

**PHP Code(multiplemethodsroute.php):**

```
<?php

    require 'Slim/Slim.php';

    /* Invoke the static "registerAutoloader()" function defined within Slim class. 
     * Register the autoloader is very important. 
     * Without doing it nothing will work.
    */ 
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

    //Instantiate Slim class in order to get a reference for the object.
    $application = new \Slim\Slim();

    $application->map(
        'products(/:id)', 
        function()
        { 
            global $application;
            $id = $application->request->get('id');
            if($id == null)
            {
                $id = $application->request->post('id');
            }
            echo "showing info about product #".$id;
        })->via('GET','POST');      

    $application->run();
?>
```

Both the files viz. multiplemethods.html and multiplemethodsroute.php are present in the same directory titled "slimsamples" at location `/var/www/slimsamples`

As I submit the HTML form by entering some number say 9565665 the **404 Page not found** message appears on the browser window.

The control is not going inside the function written for map. I tested this during debug process.

Can someone please find out the mistake I'm making here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: missing `/` in front of `products(/:id)`?

Comment: @Jasper:Thank you so much for pointing out the exact problem. After adding / infront of products(/:id) it really worked superbly for me.

Comment: @Jasper: add it as answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Slim documentation, you  are missing the leading /:

```
$application->map('/products(/:id)') ...
```